# picking the highest value from a dictionary using its key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

So the aim is to sort a word into letters and give it a score based on each letters worth. i have this working and have put it int a Dictionary using the score as the key and word as the value.
I need to find the highest scoring word that uses only the letters provided (each only used once), and if there are multiple with the same score then the first that was added to the dictionary needs to be printed. the code is as below;

```
    Dictionary<string, int> wordHolder = new Dictionary<string, int>();



    int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        string W = Console.ReadLine();


        char[] splitWord = W.ToCharArray();
        Console.Error.WriteLine(W);


        int points = splitWord.Sum(c => letterPoints.First(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(c)).Key);
        wordHolder.Add(W, points);
        Console.Error.WriteLine(points);

    }
    string LETTERS = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Error.WriteLine(LETTERS);
```

Letters is the provided characters given in a single string

Comment: What is `letterPoints`?

Comment: @Sadiq, the letterpoints is the  dictionary <int,HashSet<char>> keeping hold of the values of each of the letters, where the int is the score each is worth and char is the list of characters worth that much

Comment: You seem to use both dictionaries in reverse, looking up the Key for a Value.

Comment: SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> Class => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx  For this the key must be unique.If you want to add the same key use a SortedList.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by descending and get first element:

```
wordHolder.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First();
```

Or Order by ascending and get last element:

```
wordHolder.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Last();
```

Comment: There's nothing like using a `O(n log n)` operation to do an `O(n)` job.

Comment: The best thing to do if you want it in `O(n)` is to keep track of max value in the loop using a Key Value Pair itself and updating it .

Comment: @Sadiq how would i make sure it prints the first inputted word and check that the words contain the provided letters?

Comment: Can you show a sample output that you want i am not sure i am understanding you well here.

Comment: @Sadiq
because (word1)
11
first (word2)
8
these (word3)
8
could (word4)
8
which  (word5)
16
hicquwh  provided letters
which(This is the desired result(console.WriteLine()) but it also needs to cover if multiple are equal then the first one is the printed word

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      //  --- building up the data so the next (repeated) steps are efficient: ---

      // your words and points
      var wordHolder = new Dictionary<string, int>();

      // INSERT DATA INTO wordHolder HERE

      // create a dictionary where you can access all words and their points 
      // efficiently by the letters you have available:
      var efficientAccessByLetters = wordHolder.Select(entry =>
                                                new
                                                {
                                                  Index = new string(entry.Key.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()),
                                                  Word = entry.Key,
                                                  Points = entry.Value
                                                })
                                                .GroupBy(x => x.Index)
                                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                                              x => x.OrderByDescending(p => p.Points).ToList());

      //  --- Repeat this steps as many times as you like: ---

      while (true)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter letters available:");

        // get letters that you want to build he best word from:
        var availableLetters = Console.ReadLine();

        // normalize the letters for fast index search by sorting them
        var normalized = new string(availableLetters.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());

        if (!efficientAccessByLetters.ContainsKey(normalized))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no matching words found.");
        }
        else
        {
          // find all words and their respective points by index access
          var wordsThatMatchLetters = efficientAccessByLetters[normalized];

          // as words are sorted by points, just get the first
          var best = wordsThatMatchLetters.First();

          // output
          Console.WriteLine("Best Match: {0} for {1} points", best.Word, best.Points);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when i tried ti implement this i get errors on both the entry.Orderby(saying it does not contain a definition for orderby) and on the var normalized ()saying cannot convert from <char> to char

Comment: @TravisJeffery Ah yes, I did not have a compiler at hand. With the edit it should work.

Comment: im still getting errors with the avaliable letters line

Comment: As pasted, it compiles with VS 2015 as Console Application. Can you post the error?.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

im working in codingame

Comment: That's a runtime error. Paste the stack trace. What *was* your input?

Comment: the input is the LETTERS, they are the ones you have to use to check that the word was them
i dont know what the stack trace is

Comment: If I run this and enter "LETTERS" when asked, it prints "Sorry, no matching words found." as I would expect. Sorry, I cannot help you with that. Maybe you did not copy all of it?

Answer (score 0):

The best of way of doing it without a dictionary.

```
 public static string High(string s)
 {
    return s.Split(' ').OrderByDescending(a => a.Select(b => b - 96).Sum()).Last();
 }
```